# Android camerax take picture into variable

Tags: android, android-camerax

I need to save a taken picture in android into a variable (string)
this is my code:

```
    var imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder().build()
    val captureMode = ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY
    val flashMode = ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_AUTO
    val aspectRatio = AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { previewView.display.getRealMetrics(it) }
    val screenSize = Size(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)

    imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
        .setCaptureMode(captureMode)
        .setTargetAspectRatio(aspectRatio)
        .setFlashMode(flashMode)
        .setTargetResolution(screenSize)
        .setTargetName("CameraConference")
        .build()
```

imageCapture has a method called takePicture
I can't understand how to use imageCapture.takePicture so the output of it will be a variable (string)

Thanks

Comment: What is the format of the string? Why do you want to save it into a string, instead of the byte array provided by CameraX?

Comment: I would also like to receive it as as a byte array but not into a file
(I need to take this picture and to send it somewhere else)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ImageCapture#takePicture(Executor executor, ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback callback)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture#takePicture(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback)) API to return an in-memory picture. The returned object is an [ImageProxy](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageProxy), which include the actual bytes as well as how the bytes should be transformed to present to end users. [ImageProxy#getPlanes()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageProxy#getPlanes()) contain the buffer bytes.

To convert the ImageProxy bytes to a Bitmap, please see the code sample [here](https://github.com/owahltinez/camerax-tflite/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/camerax/tflite/YuvToRgbConverter.kt).