# How do I avoid saving captured image in my device?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

I have to create functionality for an application where I have to take pictures and save it to a SQLite database. I have implemented the camera for now using the camera intent in android, but the image gets saved to the gallery. I have read the Camer2 and CamerX API documentation and the image still gets saved to a device folder. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: "but the image gets saved to the gallery" -- that will depend on the behavior of the camera app, and there are hundreds of those. "I have read the Camer2 and CamerX API documentation and the image still gets saved to a device folder" -- not automatically. You get handed the image data in memory. What you do with that image data is up to you. Frequently, the app *wants* to store the image locally on disk, but that is not required.

Comment: As long as you have the hand to the image path, you can copy it to your external app folder, and remove the original one

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/64651558/277368 on how to get in-memory image with CameraX. Then you need to serialize the image and save it to SQLite on your own.